# How can I fix the middle column not having padding?

Tags: html, css, border

I am making a copycat Drudge Report website for practice.

While coding, I noticed that the padding doesn’t seem to work on the middle column. There’s no spaces next to the `<hr>` / separation lines, which really messes with the overall look.

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

.container {
  font-size: 12.5px;
}

.top-list ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: COURIER, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.top-list li:nth-child(3) a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.top-list li:nth-child(10) a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

.main-image {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.middle-text {
  font-family: ARIAL, VERDANA, HELVETICA;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.middle-text p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 47px;
}

.middle-text img {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-family: COURIER, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  height: 2460px;
}

.left-column img {
  width: 200px;
}

.middle-column {
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-family: COURIER, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.middle-column img {
  width: 200px;
}

.right-column {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-family: COURIER, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  height: 2460px;
}

.right-column img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Left Column -->

<div class="left-column">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="http://www.zerohedge.com/">ZERO HEDGE</a>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Right Column -->

<div class="right-column">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="images/people.jpg">
    <p><a href="https://apnews.com/article/donald-trump-pandemics-europe-basketball-meghan-markle-abc35f110e954524437eb7142912cd6a">In year dominated by pandemic, many other dramas unfolded...</a></p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Middle Column -->

<div class="middle-column">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="images/person.jpg" alt="Person">
    <hr>
    <p><a href="https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/virgin-galactic-space-plane-test-abort-b1771292.html">GALACTIC forced to abort key test flight of space plane...</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://apnews.com/article/space-tourism-new-mexico-us-news-coronavirus-pandemic-bccddfbcb8019dd7e3a58c320d5f79c4"><i>Rocket motor fails to ignite...</i></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The full HTML can be found on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/raw/yd5Z5rtL).

Comment: Syntax error at `text-align: center width: 33%;`. A semicolon is missing.

Comment: Hmm.. that seems to break it more. Now the middle text goes below the left column, and it’s centered instead of in the center but the text starts at the left (if that makes any sense). How would I correct that?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. HTML is always needed for CSS.

Comment: Edited the original post to add HTML that causes it.

Comment: why using such an ancient design technique int he first place instead of css-grid? Easier, cleaner and modern solution.

Comment: I’m really not sure what the expected result is. Where is the “Person” section supposed to go? In any case, `float` is difficult to deal with; `float: left;`, `float: right;`, and `text-align: center;` do _not_ correspond to left column, right column, and middle column, respectively. You’d need `float: left;` for all three columns, and have a width of 33 % _minus_ borders or padding, unless you use the right [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), _unless_ you don’t use a very old browser… There are better alternatives, e.g. `columns`, Flex, Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like HTML/CSS above is using [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) CSS property to achieve 3-column layout.

This is old and inefficient way (Flexbox is preferred for columns, Grid for more complex layouts).

The caveat with using `float` is that `middle-column` should not have `width` set to it and should have `margin-left` and `margin-right` which match left and right column sizes. [Here's](https://codepen.io/vburlai/pen/zYKNNGR) an example.

```css
.middle-column {
  /* width: 33%; do not apply width, it would not fit */
  margin-left: 33%; /* skip over left column */
  margin-right: 33%; /* skip over right column */
}
```

The above style should fix the issue. But I'd recommend looking at [Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) could handle this use-case and more. It's well [supported](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) by current browsers.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/vburlai/pen/dypNNGa) 3 column layout using Flexbox:

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-column {
  width: 33%;
}

.right-column {
  width: 33%;
}

.middle-column {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="left-column">
    Left column
  </div>

  <div class="middle-column">
    Middle column
  </div>

  <div class="right-column">
    Right column
  </div>
</div>
```

*P.S.*

[CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) is an even more advanced technique (as suggested in comments). It is well [supported](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) by modern browsers, but has limited functionality in Internet Explorer.

Comment: CSS-Grid is supported by every browser with exeption of ancient Internet explorer. And actually for a 3 column layout like here it would even be shorter. All you need to add for CSS is: `body { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }` You dont need to define the childs width then. Or for your samle exchange `body` with `.flex-row`

Comment: Updated note on grid support.

Comment: to shorten your css code, you can achieve the same result with: `.flex-row { display: flex; flex-direction: row; } .flex-row div { width: 33%; }`